# DocumentFormat.OpenXml Nuget package have many dependencies like Microsoft.NetCore.Platforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, openxml

I'm doing some Ms excel automation in my app, however upon polling DocumentFormat.OpenXml Nuget package many dependencies were downloaded along with it such as:

- Microsoft.NetCore.Platforms
- Microsoft.Win32.Primitives
- NetStandard.Library
- System.AppContext
- System.Collections
- System.Collections.Concurrent
- System.Console
- System.Diagnosics.Debug
- System.Net.Http
- System.Net.Sockets

And many other in spite the the fact that I'm targeting .Net framework not .Net core or standard. in fact I don't need those extra references in my class library project. Why those dependencies were installed? and is their any method that allows download only the specified package without those dependencies?

Comment: Before applying some optimizations, with the risk of spending a lot of time and come up with  faulty solution: why does this matters in you usecase?; most of these dependencies actual make sense.

Comment: If the package is targetting .NET Standard 1.x, then those packages are necessary.

Comment: @Stefan my code are doing a simple tasks of creating excel workbooks and if I removed those references the code still run as expected so I'm wondering if their is a way of getting the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll without the rest of the NetCore nor Standard assemblies.

Comment: It's in your output directory.

Comment: @Stefan yes all of the assemblies are available in the output folder

Comment: `so I'm wondering if their is a way of getting the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll`, well, there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why those dependencies were installed? and is their any method that allows download only the specified package without those dependencies?

This is the issue about the nuget package itself. When you check the dependencies of the package on the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/#):

[image]

We could to know the package add wrong dependencies (.NET Standard 1.3) to the `.net framework` project.

I have ever reported the [similar issue](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/953) on the github.

To resolve this issue, you can use the version **2.7.2** instead of 2.8.1 or just remove those extra references.

Note: To solve this issue finally, we need to report this issue to the author and wait author update this package:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've removed the unnecessary .net core and standard packages and it works fine, I'll test the other option of changing the version thanks